# d3 synchronizing 2 separate zoom behaviors

Tags: d3.js, d3fc

I have the following d3/d3fc chart

https://codepen.io/parliament718/pen/BaNQPXx

The chart has a zoom behavior for the main area and a separate zoom behavior for the y-axis.
The y-axis can be dragged to rescale.

The problem I'm having trouble solving is that after dragging the y-axis to rescale and then subsequently panning the chart, there is a "jump" in the chart.

Obviously the 2 zoom behaviors have a disconnect and need to be synchronized but I'm racking my brain trying to fix this.

```
const mainZoom = zoom()
    .on('zoom', () => {
       xScale.domain(t.rescaleX(x2).domain());
       yScale.domain(t.rescaleY(y2).domain());
    });

const yAxisZoom = zoom()
    .on('zoom', () => {
        const t = event.transform;
        yScale.domain(t.rescaleY(y2).domain());
        render();
    });

const yAxisDrag = drag()
    .on('drag', (args) => {
        const factor = Math.pow(2, -event.dy * 0.01);
        plotArea.call(yAxisZoom.scaleBy, factor);
    });
```

The desired behavior is for zooming, panning, and/or rescaling the axis to always apply the transformation from wherever the previous action finished, without any "jumps".

Answer (score 16):

OK, so I've had another go at this - as mentioned in my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61073772/249933), the biggest issue you need to overcome is that the d3-zoom only permits symmetrical scaling. This is something that has been [widely discussed](https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom/issues/48), and I believe Mike Bostock is addressing this in the next release.

So, in order to overcome the issue, you need to use multiple zoom behaviour. I have created a chart that has three, one for each axis and one for the plot area. The X & Y zoom behaviours are used to scale the axes. Whenever a zoom event is raised by the X & Y zoom behaviours, their translation values are copied across to the plot area. Likewise, when a translation occurs on the plot area, the x & y components are copied to the respective axis behaviours.

Scaling on the plot area is a little more complicated as we need to maintain the aspect ratio. In order to achieve this I store the previous zoom transform and use the scale delta to work out a suitable scale to apply to the X & Y zoom behaviours.

For convenience, I've wrapped all of this up into a chart component:

```
const interactiveChart = (xScale, yScale) => {
  const zoom = d3.zoom();
  const xZoom = d3.zoom();
  const yZoom = d3.zoom();

  const chart = fc.chartCartesian(xScale, yScale).decorate(sel => {
    const plotAreaNode = sel.select(".plot-area").node();
    const xAxisNode = sel.select(".x-axis").node();
    const yAxisNode = sel.select(".y-axis").node();

    const applyTransform = () => {
      // apply the zoom transform from the x-scale
      xScale.domain(
        d3
          .zoomTransform(xAxisNode)
          .rescaleX(xScaleOriginal)
          .domain()
      );
      // apply the zoom transform from the y-scale
      yScale.domain(
        d3
          .zoomTransform(yAxisNode)
          .rescaleY(yScaleOriginal)
          .domain()
      );
      sel.node().requestRedraw();
    };

    zoom.on("zoom", () => {
      // compute how much the user has zoomed since the last event
      const factor = (plotAreaNode.__zoom.k - plotAreaNode.__zoomOld.k) / plotAreaNode.__zoomOld.k;
      plotAreaNode.__zoomOld = plotAreaNode.__zoom;

      // apply scale to the x & y axis, maintaining their aspect ratio
      xAxisNode.__zoom.k = xAxisNode.__zoom.k * (1 + factor);
      yAxisNode.__zoom.k = yAxisNode.__zoom.k * (1 + factor);

      // apply transform
      xAxisNode.__zoom.x = d3.zoomTransform(plotAreaNode).x;
      yAxisNode.__zoom.y = d3.zoomTransform(plotAreaNode).y;

      applyTransform();
    });

    xZoom.on("zoom", () => {
      plotAreaNode.__zoom.x = d3.zoomTransform(xAxisNode).x;
      applyTransform();
    });

    yZoom.on("zoom", () => {
      plotAreaNode.__zoom.y = d3.zoomTransform(yAxisNode).y;
      applyTransform();
    });

    sel
      .enter()
      .select(".plot-area")
      .on("measure.range", () => {
        xScaleOriginal.range([0, d3.event.detail.width]);
        yScaleOriginal.range([d3.event.detail.height, 0]);
      })
      .call(zoom);

    plotAreaNode.__zoomOld = plotAreaNode.__zoom;

    // cannot use enter selection as this pulls data through
    sel.selectAll(".y-axis").call(yZoom);
    sel.selectAll(".x-axis").call(xZoom);

    decorate(sel);
  });

  let xScaleOriginal = xScale.copy(),
    yScaleOriginal = yScale.copy();

  let decorate = () => {};

  const instance = selection => chart(selection);

  // property setters not show 

  return instance;
};
```

Here's a pen with the working example:

https://codepen.io/colineberhardt-the-bashful/pen/qBOEEGJ

Comment: Colin, thanks so much for giving this another go. I opened your codepen and noticed that it doesnt work as expected. In my codepen, dragging the Y axis re-scales the chart (this is desired behavior). In your codepen, dragging the axis simply pans the chart.

Comment: I've managed to create one that allows you to drag on both the y-scale and the plot area https://codepen.io/colineberhardt-the-bashful/pen/mdeJyrK - but zooming in the plot area is quite a challenge

Answer (score 7):

There are a couple of issues with your code, one which is easy to solve, and one which is not ...

Firstly, the d3-zoom works by storing a transform on the selected DOM element(s) - you can see this via the `__zoom` property. When the user interacts with the DOM element, this transform is updated and events emitted. Therefore, if you have to different zoom behaviours both of which are controlling the pan / zoom of a single element, you need to keep these transforms synchronised.

You can copy the transform as follows:

```
selection.call(zoom.transform, d3.event.transform);
```

However, this will also cause zoom events to be fired from the target behaviour also.

An alternative is to copy directly to the 'stashed' transform property:

```
selection.node().__zoom = d3.event.transform;
```

However, there is a bigger problem with what you are trying to achieve. The d3-zoom transform is stored as 3 components of a transformation matrix:

https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom#zoomTransform

As a result, the zoom can only represent a symmetrical scaling together with a translation. Your asymmetrical zoom as a applied to the x-axis cannot be faithfully represented by this transform and re-applied to the plot-area.

Comment: Thanks Colin, I wish any of this made sense to me but I don't understand what the solution is. I will add a 500 bounty to this question as soon as I can and hopefully someone can help fix my codepen.

Comment: No worries, not an easy issue to fix, but a bounty might attract some offers of help.

Answer (score 6):

This is [an upcoming feature](https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom/issues/48), as already noted by @ColinE. The original code is always doing a "temporal zoom" that is un-synced from the transform matrix.

The best workaround is to tweak the `xExtent` range so that the graph believes that there are additional candles on the sides. This can be achieved by adding pads to the sides. The `accessors`, instead of being,

```js
[d => d.date]
```

becomes,

```js
[
  () => new Date(taken[0].date.addDays(-xZoom)), // Left pad
  d => d.date,
  () => new Date(taken[taken.length - 1].date.addDays(xZoom)) // Right pad
]
```

*Sidenote: Note that there is a `pad` function that [should do that](https://d3fc.io/api/extent-api.html#time) but for some reason it works only once and never updates again that's why it is added as an `accessors`.*

*Sidenote 2: Function `addDays` added as a prototype (not the best thing to do) just for simplicity.*

Now the zoom event modifies our X zoom factor, `xZoom`,

```js
zoomFactor = Math.sign(d3.event.sourceEvent.wheelDelta) * -5;
if (zoomFactor) xZoom += zoomFactor;
```

**It is important to read the differential directly from `wheelDelta`**. This is where the unsupported feature is: We can't read from `t.x` as it will change even if you drag the Y axis.

Finally, recalculate `chart.xDomain(xExtent(data.series));` so that the new extent is available.

### See the working demo without the jump here: https://codepen.io/adelriosantiago/pen/QWjwRXa?editors=0011

*Fixed: Zoom reversing, improved behaviour on trackpad.*

Technically you could also tweak `yExtent` by adding extra `d.high` and `d.low`'s. Or even both `xExtent` and `yExtent` to avoid using the transform matrix at all.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately the zoom behavior here is really messed up. The zoom feels very jerky and in some cases even reverses direction several times (using macbook trackpad). The zoom behavior needs to stay the same as the original pen.

Comment: I have updated the pen with a few improvements, particularly the reversing zoom.

Comment: I'm going to award you the bounty for your effort and I'm starting a second bounty because I still need an answer with better zooming/pan. Unfortunately this method based on delta changes is still jerky and not smooth when zooming, and when panning it pans too fast. I suspect that you can probably adjust the factor endlessly and still not get smooth behavior. I'm looking for an answer that does not change the zooming/panning behavior of the original pen.

Comment: I've also adjusted the original pen to zoom only along the X-axis. That is the deserved behavior and I now realize it may complicate the answer.

Answer (score 1):

A solution is given here https://observablehq.com/@d3/x-y-zoom
It uses a main zoom behavior that gets the gestures, and two ancillary zooms that store the transforms.

Comment: Thanks, I have seen this solution and have not been able to figure out how to integrate it into my codepen. If you have a way please show. Started a bounty just for you ;) Just providing a link is not a good answer. Thank you!

Comment: OK, sorry. The code has comments, let me know if there are specific points that need more explanations.

Comment: Thanks. For starters, your example doesn't have "drag to rescale the y-axis" (it pans using a single zoom behavior), so it misses the most important part of this question and the reason why I've resorted to using multiple zoom behaviors

Comment: Fil's x-y-zoom fork with "drag to rescale the y-axis" https://observablehq.com/d/1e35e556458a0837